# using a xspf file on both ubuntu and windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, vlc

i have computer with dual boot between windows and ubuntu i have partitioned the windows side between a os partition C: and a data partition D:

i also have a massive vlc playlist on my D: windows partition that i would like to play on ubuntu.
Of course i understand that the path to the same file will be different

as a solution i suspected a symbolic link would work

As D: is the partition where all data is I searched for the path to the partition which turned out to be /media/fuseteam/Data

After searching I similar case so adapted the code from there based on what I found

as such i tried "ln -s /media/fuseteam/Data/D:" in the terminal and i couldn't get the playlist to work i have checked if i spelled everything correctly including caps

how should i make the link so that the same playlist file can work on both operating systems?

Comment: I am aware hence why I searched for the path to what windows calls D: and found /media/fuseteam/Data

Comment: What I'm trying to do is tell vlc that where it sees "D:" in the file path it should search in "/media/fuseteam/Data/"

Comment: but how will there be a D: in the file path? are you trying to make a playlist work?  /media/fuseteam/Data/ is the path to the partition

Comment: That is what I wrote, no? Yes I'm trying to get the playlist to work

Comment: I clarified the post and added additional info

Comment: you won't be able to get a windows playlist to work if they have file paths in them. the main reason is that windows uses \ and linux uses / to denote subdirectories. so even if you create a simlink "D:" the file path would have to be edited from "D:\file" to "D:/file"

Comment: From the error log I already saw "D:/file" aka i saw the complete file path with only "/" instead of the usual "\" hmm,  If I want to test it where should I make the symlink?

Comment: since there is not a preceeding / it will look for folder D: in it's current working directory

Comment: So the directory where the playlist file is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66792/discussion-between-ravery-and-fuseteam).

Answer (score 0):

i found it! after examining the error better i realized it was looking for /D: rather than just D:

and appearently by using ""ln -s /media/fuseteam/Data/D:" it created a file in my home folder

so the correct command was "sudo ln -s /media/fuseteam/Data /D:"